# Which two points should a bookshelf be supported at to minimize maximum strain?

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

Let's say I have a bookshelf supported by two brackets, like in this picture:

[image: picture]

The shelf is not otherwise supported at its ends.

I'm going to load weight uniformly onto this shelf. If we model the shelf as the unit interval $0\le x\le 1$, where should the two brackets be placed to minimize the strain on the wood at the point of maximum strain?

(I haven't tried much because I do not know how to begin modeling this. My intuition is wavering between $x=\frac 14,\frac 34$ and $x=\frac 16,\frac 56$, but I don't have much confidence that either of those is correct.)

Comment: More generic stuff on bending beams. Enjoy! https://courses.washington.edu/me354a/chap3.pdf

Comment: @tuna you have to be a little careful as to whether the two supports just provide a simple vertical force or can actually provide some horizontal force and some moment.  Looking at the picture, those brackets look pretty substantial and firmly attached to the board so I suspect they will play a substantial role in strengenthing the shelf.

Comment: @tuna: The beam shown in the picture is an overhanging fixed beam which requires superposition of bending moment diagrams for a fixed beam. Only after drawing bending moment diagram for given fixed beam you will be able to minimize the bending moment or strain.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to minimize the maximum bending moment of the shelf, you should locate the supports so that the positive bending moment equals the negative bending moment.

Moving the supports farther apart (increasing the overhang) increases the positive bending (a "smile") while moving them closer together increases the negative bending (a "frown").

See the following: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-place-the-supports-such-that-the-maximum-bending-moment-is-the-least-possible-in-a-simply-supported-beam Although, the link applies to a simply supported beam.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well spotted, that man! Takes me back to year 2 at Uni that stuff! +1 from me.

Comment: @Gert Me too. Though for me it was 55 years ago!

Comment: That was a tough course and I've never used it ever since (35 years)

Comment: I used to teach it, along with statics, thermodynamics and electrical, for about 15 years to engineers reviewing  for the professional engineering fundamentals exam here in the states.